# getAllDefinitions Exception in Proton CEP

Tags: fiware

I have deployed Proton CEP on our own server on CentOS and Tomcat 7.

The call to 
`/ProtonOnWebServerAdmin/resources/definitions`

is failing with the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.ibm.hrl.proton.admin.webapp.resources.DefinitionsResource.getAllDefinitions(DefinitionsResource.java:76)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:151)
org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:65)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:48)
org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:119)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Other APIs like work fine. For example:

PUT `ProtonOnWebServerAdmin/resources/instances/ProtonOnWebServer`
returns 200 OK

I can also successfully change the stage of the running instance with: `ProtonOnWebServerAdmin/resources/instances/ProtonOnWebServer`

Additionally, the folder where the definitions should be is empty. In `ProtonAdmin.properties` it is configured as `definitions-repository=`/home/xmarine/ProtonDefinitions`

The permissions on that folder are:

```
[xmarine@app-fiware ProtonOnWebServerAdmin]$ ls -al /home/xmarine/ProtonDefinitions/
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 tomcat  tomcat     6 dec  8 12:18 .
drwx------ 7 xmarine xmarine 4096 dec 14 14:40 ..
```

Could you help me solve this?

Comment: Are you sure you configured ProtonAdmin.properties correctly (manager-username, manager-password, tomcat-server-port, tomcat-jmx-port) ? - see http://proactive-technology-online.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Proton-InstallationAndAdminGuide/index.html

Comment: I had. I have now changed the `definitions-repository` in `ProtonAdmin.properties` to `/opt/definitions` and I now longer receive the error above. Instead it now returns 200 OK and and empty array `[]`.
So I go to the Authoring tool, and export the project, which also returns "Successfully added ProjectName", but when running `GET /ProtonOnWebServerAdmin/resources/definitions` again, it still returns an empty array. However `GET /ProtonOnWebServerAdmin/resources/instances/ProtonOnWebServer` return that the ProjectName definition is started.

Comment: Finally, modifying the permissions of /opt/definitions to the tomcat user finally made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to modify the `definitions-repository` in `ProtonAdmin.properties`.

Previously it was: `/home/xmarine/ProtonDefinitions`
The new one was: `/opt/definitions`

Also, I had to make the user `tomcat` is owner of that folder with:

`sudo chown tomcat:root /opt/definitions`.